# Using font icons with declarative UIs

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

While developing a new application with Vaadin 7.4.6, I found myself needing to supply icons for various buttons. Normally I'd be doing this with `dashboardButton.setIcon(FontAwesome.BAR_CHART_O);` but I'm trying to do this declaratively.

Now, I can achieve a similar effect if I include a span inside the button definition like below...

```
<v-button _id="dashboardButton" primary-style-name="valo-menu-item" style-name="borderless">
    <span class="v-icon FontAwesome">&#xF080</span>
    Dashboard
</v-button>
```

... and I already know that the [books mentions that mapping objects to attributes is not supported](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/application.declarative.html#application.declarative.attributes.parameters) (at least so far), but I was wondering if anyone knows a better alternative or if there's a way of using the font-icons enums instead of the code points, eg: `FontAwesome.BAR_CHART_O` instead of `&#xF080`.

Comment: created an enhancement request here since it would be nice to have - https://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/18840#ticket

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following also works (at least in v7.5.0 and Valo).

```
<v-button icon="fonticon://FontAwesome/f0c7">Save</v-button>
```

You still have to use the hex code but it's a little more elegant than your example. It's also what the Eclipse WYSIWYG Vaadin designer uses.

---

Later edit: [Detailed guide to creating and using custom font icons with Vaadin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39708331/how-to-set-custom-font-icon-when-using-a-vaadin-declarative-ui)

Comment: Forgot to mark this as the answer, sry about that. It would still be nice to support enum values, but until then this is the cleanest way