# How to set custom font icon when using a Vaadin declarative UI?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I am using a custom font icon set as described at the wiki article [Font icons in Vaadin 7.2](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Using+font+icons). Everything works fine.

However, if I use the declarative UI I am not able to get it working.

This is my code so far:

```
<vaadin-panel caption="..." style-name="..." icon="fonticon://IcoCustom/58884" size-full>
```

**UPDATE**

Allowed syntax:

- `font://INDUSTRY` (deprecated syntax, assumes FontAwesome font icon)
- `fonticon://FontAwesome/f275` (font family/codepoint in hex. decimal values not allowed)
- `fonticon://MyFonticon/e900` (for setup custom font icons see @Morfic's answer)

Does *not* work:

- `fonticon://INDUSTRY`
- `fonticon://FontAwesome/INDUSTRY`

Comment: It's the hex-code without `0x` eg: `icon="fonticon://IcoCustom/E604"`. I'll post a detailed answer in a few minutes...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note:** Tested on Vaadin 7.7.3

1) Went to  [icomoon](http://icomoon.io/app) as suggested in the [Using font-icons wiki article](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Using+font+icons) and selected only 1 icon, home (Notice the assigned code `e900`, that's what we'll use later.):

[image: icomoon]

2) Copied the `fonts` folder content as per the same tutorial, but renamed all the files to `myfont*`:
[image: theme font setup]

3) Created the theme files. Notice that there is a discrepancy between the wiki article, and the [Vaadin docs theme-font section](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/themes/themes-fonts.html) regarding the `@import` path, the correct being the one from the docs:

- wiki [*wrong*]: `@include font(IcoMoon, '../../fonticondemo/fonts/icomoon');`
- docs [**right**]: `@include font(MyFontFamily,               '../../../../mytheme/fonts/myfontfamily');`

**styles.scss**

```css
@import "mytheme.scss";

@include font(myfont, '../../../../mytheme/fonts/myfont');

/* This file prefixes all rules with the theme name to avoid causing conflicts with other themes. */
/* The actual styles should be defined in mytheme.scss */
.mytheme {
  @include mytheme;
}
```

**mytheme.scss**

```css
@import "../valo/valo";

@mixin mytheme {
  @include valo;
}
```

3) Then created the design file and component, nothing fancy, just a layout with a button:

**java**

```java
@DesignRoot
public class MyDeclarativeComponent extends VerticalLayout {
    public MyDeclarativeComponent() {
        Design.read(this);
    }
}
```

**html** (notice the `e900` code used)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <com_example_declarative_font-my-declarative-component>
            <vaadin-button icon="fonticon://myfont/e900" plain-text>My button</vaadin-button>
        </com_example_declarative_font-my-declarative-component>
    </body>
</html>
```

4) Optional enum, shamelessly copied from the Vaadin implementation of `FontAwesome`

```java
public enum MyFont implements FontIcon {
    HOME(0xe900);

    public static final String FONT_FAMILY = "myfont";
    private int codepoint;

    private MyFont(int codepoint) {
        this.codepoint = codepoint;
    }

    public String getMIMEType() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(FontIcon.class.getSimpleName() + " should not be used where a MIME type is needed.");
    }

    public String getFontFamily() {
        return FONT_FAMILY;
    }

    public int getCodepoint() {
        return this.codepoint;
    }

    public String getHtml() {
        return GenericFontIcon.getHtml(FONT_FAMILY, this.codepoint);
    }

    public static MyFont fromCodepoint(final int codepoint) {
        for (MyFont f : values()) {
            if (f.getCodepoint() == codepoint) {
                return f;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Codepoint " + codepoint + " not found in FontAwesome");
    }
}
```

5) And a basic `UI` implementation:

```
@Theme("mytheme")
@PreserveOnRefresh
@SpringUI(path = "/")
@Title("Vaadin demo app")
public class MyUi extends UI {

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        Layout content = new VerticalLayout();
        content.setSizeFull();
        setContent(content);
        content.addComponent(new MyDeclarativeComponent());
    }
}
```

6) Result:

[image: result]

7) Bonus - printing declarative format for a component: you can to this in at least 2 simple ways

a) `Design.write(this, System.out);`

b) [Vaadin debug mode](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-debug.html) - use the included tool to print the design to your console
[image: vaadin debug mode]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. When using Java, it already works for me. The only missing part was using the hex code without `0x` prefix. Bonus 7b is new for me, nice!

Comment: @rmuller no problem, 7 a/b is usually how I figure out these kinds of problems or when I have doubts, without looking at the sources or debugging :-)

Comment: Yes, that is a very nice advice. I am going to to it the same way next time.